# Abstract repository and @Entity annotation inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I implement a custom `EntityRepository` in a Symfony2 application.

I have an AbstractEntity (used as parent of some entities) :

```
/**
 * Abstract Entity.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Util\Entity\AbstractRepository")
 */
abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The custom `EntityRepository` :

```
/**
 * Abstract Repository.
 */
class AbstractRepository extends Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * Handles resource not found from find.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function findOrFail($id)
    {
        if (null == $entity = $this->find($id)) {
            return $this->fail();
        }

        return $entity;
    }

   //...
}
```

And one of the entities that extends from `AbstractEntity` :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="tags_sport")
 */
class Tag extends AbstractEntity
{
     // ...
}
```

The custom repository is declared once in my AbstractEntity using `@ORM\Entity` annotation.
I want make my entities use the same repository without redeclare it.

But an error occurs  :

```
Class "App\SportBundle\Entity\Tag" sub class of "App\Util\Entity\AbstractEntity" is not a valid entity or mapped super class
```

It's caused by the missing `@ORM\Entity` annotation in the child entity.

But nothing change.
If I add the `@ORM\Entity` annotation in the child entity, it will use the default `EntityRepository`.

How can I override the default `EntityRepository` for each entities extending from the `AbstractEntity` ?

**EDIT** I accept @Rvanlaak answer thanks to a gist given in the answer comments.
The final solution including the whole custom Repository in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chalasr/77be8eee5e3ecd3c06ec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two separate things, having an abstract parent entity, and having an abstract parent repository.

By default every entity will use the `EntityRepository`. The entity can have one repository, which can be defined via the `ORM\Entity` annotation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Let's say you create `TagRepository` yourself, there will be no problem with extending from your `AbstractRepository`.

Second, having an abstract entity. This is like telling Doctrine that your entity has a parent class. This isn't possible. The solution for that is to use `traits`. Found a nice article about that here: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-traits-doctrine-entities/

Comment: I know the classic way (one Repository for one Entity, which can be extends from whatever I want).  My question is how avoid this. I don't want many empty repositories extending from my AbstractRepository. For now, I use the same repository for all my entities, using the repositoryClass attribute. I just want remove this statement which is duplicated in all entities. My goal is : Use a main repository for each entities extending from a specific class. My AbstractEntity is more a Base class which avoid duplicated code like Identifier (which is the same for all entities).

Comment: Ah now I see. That would be possible by decorating the `RepositoryFactory` that is registered via the `DoctrineBundle` extension. https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php#L455-L457 Did also find a related Gist about that here https://gist.github.com/docteurklein/9778800

Comment: thank you for your interest, I will try the gist and wait for more answers before accept yours.