# Doctrine Entity Repository how to add 'andWhere' to all 'find*' functions?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

For legacy reasons I have table that is used for many purposes. Only subset of rows is relevant to Entity I'm writing. Criteria is simple, just check `'project'` field for specific value.

Instead of reimplementing find, findAll, findByName, findByID, findBy.... Just notify doctrine to append single condition to them all. Is that possible without reimplementing each and every find* ?

Or maybe it can be done on lover level still?

**UPDATE:**

- Reworked question, to specify what kind of solution would be acceptable.

Comment: Filters might help: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html See here for configuring filters in Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Answer (score 2):

An available easy-to-use solution is to create a `Repository` with your custom `find` function.

Then, if all your entities has a specific `Repository`, make them (`Repository`) extending from yours (which contains the custom `find` method), otherwise (you doesn't have a `Repository` per entity), assign the repository to all your entities with the `repositoryClass` option of the `@ORM\Entity` annotation like :

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourMainRepository")
```

Otherwise, if you doesn't want put any repository in your entities, override the whole default repository and customise the find method.

I already used the last option because of a specific need, also I invite you to see the following question :

[Abstract repository and @Entity annotation inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766175/abstract-repository-and-entity-annotation-inheritance)

Look at the solution wich contains a gist of all required steps for override the default doctrine repository.

See [Custom Repository classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

Comment: Ok. I was not specific enough. What I want is to not reimplement find, findAll, findByName, findByID, findBy.... but just notify doctrine to append single condition to them all. Is that possible without reimplementing each and every find* ?

Comment: Ok, the @Cerad option from comments is surely the better alternative to globally modify the repository comportment .

Answer (score 1):

**Entity**:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Phrase
*
* @ORM\Table(name="User")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
*/
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
.............................................................
.............................................................
.............................................................
```

Your **Repository**:

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /** For example **/
    public function getByName($name)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
         ->where('u.name = :name')->setParameter('name', $name)
         ->andWhere('u.lastname LIKE :name')->setParameter('lastname', '%'.$name.'%');

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

In Your Controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $userRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
    $userName = $userRepository->getByName($name);
```

..................................................................................
..................................................................................